# How to set select tag to readonly before ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to set select tag to readonly before ajax success ?

i use this but not work

```
$("#tower").prop('readonly', true);
```

then i use this , but i not get value from select tag

```
$("#tower").attr("disabled", true);
```

How can i set readonly select tag ?

Comment: I don't think select has `readonly` attribute and when you disable, you will not be able to get the value of drop down. **The best way is to get the value of the drop down before you disable and use it later when you need it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way here is to keep `select` element disabled and add an hidden input to get the value. Of course you have to set the value of hidden field the same as select.

Answer (score 0):

there is no readonly attr in select tag.

what I understood from your question is that you want to display the options but don't want to allow users to select it. if this your requirement then use the following code

> $(document).ready(function(e){
>                $('select').children('option').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
>   
>   }

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jquery to disable the select drop down and still get the value from it.

```
$("#myselect").attr("disabled", true);
alert($("#myselect").val());
```

Here is a tiny jsfiddle to demonstrate that: http://jsfiddle.net/leica/sphgbooq/

Comment: Not sure why the down vote since the code snippet demonstrably shows it is possible.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted but he's asking how to get a disabled `select`'s value to be POSTED.